# ENOENT error when serving React App on Azure

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, azure

I have a React website hosted on Azure and successfully serving up pages without a problem.

However, I often get error messages in the Web App logs such as:

```
2021-03-01T15:01:33.957751902Z 15:01:33 0|static-page-server-8080  | [2021-03-01T15:01:33.956Z] 
Error while serving /home/site/wwwroot/build/profile with content-type text/plain : 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/build/profile'
```

This error, for example, occurs when I navigate to:
https://www.webaddress.com/account/profile

To be clear the pages are still served without a problem. So why am I receiving this error? And how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

First, validate the distribution folder and check the file index.html,
the labels have to be like this

```
 <base href="/">
```

and you "outputPath" have to be like this "dist",

```
          "outputPath": "dist",
```

Best regards

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear what you're suggesting. Which labels have to be like that? And where would I set outputPath?