# ENOENT: no such file or directory error when serving React App on Azure

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I am having the same issue with my React app as asked in [ENOENT error when serving React App on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424878/enoent-error-when-serving-react-app-on-azure)

The pages are served correctly but my log shows

```
"Error while serving /home/site/wwwroot/policy with content-type text/plain : ENOENT: no such file or directory."
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Hi @sachin, can you share the code and also the project directory to know more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your react web app is serving correctly and still you are receiving this error is because of the Web app cache, And node_modules folder containing some old cached files. This is a common error with **`npm packages`**.

In order to resolve this error, Refer this [**Blog**](https://www.codejourney.net/how-to-fix-npm-err-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rename/)  and the SO thread answer by Hasna Ibraheem **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-node-js-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory).**

Delete the node_modules folder manually or by running the git clean command below:-

```js
git clean -fdx

#Now run npm install again
npm install
```

One more way to fix this issue is to run the commands below locally or directly in the Azure Web app Kudu console.

```js
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm run build
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Logs:-**

[image]

You can **ssh or bash** into the Web app Kudu console and  cross check if there's any file in policy with content type text/plain and remove it  or validate it in your local or github source code and add it again.

*Inspect the files like below:-*

**Kudu Bash and SSH:-**

```
ls
cd site
ls
cd wwwroot
ls
```

[image]